# Ditch JS fallback when using HTML5 form validation?

Tags: html, forms, validation, contact-form

What are important considerations if ditching JavaScript fallbacks?

For cases where HTML5 form validation is used for simple, 3-field contact forms:

- Name
- Email
- Message

Also assuming that HTML5 validation is **coupled with good back-end validation** (e.g. PHP) to prevent security threats.

While a fallback is [still being suggested](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/) as good-practice from a code point of view, this has UX considerations as well because from all the modern ones, only [mobile browsers lack support for HTML5 form validation](http://caniuse.com/form-validation) — it will depend on the purpose of the contact form and website, but it may or may not be a problem if certain fields go unvalidated.

Answer (score 1):

You should not drop Javascript fallbacks for form validation yet.

IE10 as a stable version is only available on Windows 8. It's still in beta state for windows 7 (and it's still not decided if MS will ever roll it out as an automatic update for 7) and will most likely **never** be available on Vista and XP which still have considerable market share. So Internet Explorer 8 and 9 are unlikely to disappear so soon.

Also, don't underestimate the mobile market. iPads and Android-based tablets are still gaining importance.

Comment: Fair point! But I wasn't underestimating regarding the mobile. I was simply putting it out there: "it may or may not be a problem if certain fields go unvalidated [on mobile]". It'll depend on the specific site in question, and the purpose of the contact form.

Comment: So your question could be rephrased as "do I need form validation when I don't need form validation?"